# dmidecode - which section exactly report maximum amount of supported RAM

Tags: memory-limit

Manufacturer of my motherboard reports a maximum of 4GB (2GB on each slot, it has two memory slot).

By reading dmidecode output I read:

```
Memory Controller Information
    Error Detecting Method: 8-bit Parity
    Error Correcting Capabilities:
            None
    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 4096 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 8192 MB
    Supported Speeds:
            70 ns
            60 ns
    Supported Memory Types:
            Standard
            EDO
    Memory Module Voltage: 5.0 V
    Associated Memory Slots: 2
            0x0006
            0x0007
    Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities: None
```

And then:

```
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2
```

Which is the right info?
4GB of "Maximum capacity" in "Phisical Memory Array" section, or 8192 MB by reading under "Controller information" "Maximum Total Memory Size" ?

An other question: could dmidecode output be affected by limits of operating system?
On my PC is running a 32bit system... So one could suspect that 4GB of maximum capacity are related to OS limit instead of hardware limits.

Anyway, my motherboard is an ASUS P5N-MX (chipset nForce 630i/ Geforce 7050)
[www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5NMX/](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5NMX/)

No chances to reach 8 GB of RAM (4GB + 4GB)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clearly? Ok, but then why manufacturer says 4GB is maximum amount? and why dmidecode "Physical Memory Array" section reports "Maximum Capacity: 4 GB"?

Comment: Yes;  You are correct.  The controller supports 8 GB, but your system will either not accept he other 4 GB or simply not POST.  I failed to look at the specification of the motherboard, because it wasn't included, in the question itself.

Comment: @Joe Your chipset is actually *NVIDIA GeForce 7050/nForce **610i***. This chipset is *so old* that I'd be surprised if it (or the BIOS for that matter) knows how to talk to more than 4GB RAM.  I have answered your question below but, if I find anything more, I'll update it.

Answer (score 4):

The output from dmidecode is nonsense. 5V for DDR2 RAM? 60/70ns?  Are we back in the i486 days?

I would not trust that info.  Instead, trust what ASUS says.  They created the motherboard, so go with their specs:

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5NMX/specifications/

As you can see, the maximum supported RAM is 4GB.  You can *try* for 8GB -- it *might* work, it might not work at all, and in the worst case it may seem to work but the system will be unstable.

I do have to ask the "why" question.  I'm curious.  Is it worth it?  8GB for something so dated?

**UPDATE:** According to reputable documentation, dmidecode output [cannot be trusted](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/):

> Beware that DMI data have proven to be too unreliable to be blindly trusted. Dmidecode does not scan your hardware, it only reports what the BIOS told it to.

Comment: Thanks misha, could a single 4GB module be supported in your opinion? or should be better to install 2 x 2GB ? Dual channel technology seems unsopported, so I could try to buy a 4GB module and  set it up with one of  two old 1GB... And if a 64bit system will see a total of 5GB, then I could try to add an other 4GB (4+4). What do you think about?